# Convergence of a certain series of Primes

Tags: number-theory, convergence-divergence, analytic-number-theory

This is a problem from Alan Baker's Comprehensive Course in Number Theory. We have to show that $\displaystyle \sum\limits_{p} \frac{1}{p (\log\log p)^{\delta}}$ converges for all $\delta >1$.Here summation is over primes I tried to prove it by considering the series $\displaystyle \sum\limits \frac{1}{n (\log\log n)^{\delta}}$ and showing that it converges. But I was not able to prove it. If anyone can help it would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $p_n$ denotes the $n$th prime, the Prime Number Theorem implies
$$p_n (\log \log (p_n))^{\delta} \sim n \log (n) (\log \log (n))^\delta.$$
The convergence of the series follows by comparison.

Comment: I understand that you have put $p_n \sim n \log n $ but can we substitute it this way will the error term cause no problem

Comment: @happymath: Good question! In this case there is no such problem since, if $u_n \sim v_n$ with $v_n \to +\infty$, then $\log(u_n) \sim \log(v_n)$. Proof: $\log(u_n) = \log (v_n) + \log(\frac{u_n}{v_n})$ and $\log \frac{u_n}{v_n} \to 0$.

Comment: I got it thanks but do we really need prime number theorem cant we just use the chebyshev extimates

Comment: @happymath. Yes, it's enough here.

Comment: what happens if we take the sum over all numbers will it still converge?

Comment: @happymath: Yes. You can check this with the Integral Test for convergence. Actually, the series converges iff $\delta > 1$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19467/discussion-between-happymath-and-simeon).